WhatsApp using prepaid minutes
I have noticed that WhatsApp is using my prepaid minutes.
I have a phone with prepaid minutes and am not on any data-plan. For internet I use WiFi connectivity.
WhatsApp claims that there is no charge for sending messages, yet I notice that my prepaid minutes are just disappearing fast.
I have asked a person at TMobile about this and he suggested to turn on airplane mode or turn off the SIM card. Airplane mode turns off the WiFi, so that does not work at all.  I will have to turn off the SIM card. I cannot yet verify that this will solve the problem, but it is annoying to constantly have to switch my SIM card status.
Has anybody encountered this? Is WhatsApp using false advertising?

Whatsapp doesn't make use of cellular phone system, only data - cellular of WiFi whatever is active. Not sure what you mean by "prepaid minutes" normally you charge money not minutes to a prepaid SIM. If you want to use Whatsapp without costs make sure you always have WiFi connection or disable mobile data connection.

I did have "International Data Roaming" on, but I am basically mostly at home with a WiFi connection.
You are right. I have "pre-paid" ... I go to TMobile and buy "time" to be able to use the network. TMobile charges fees on the money I paid.
But that is why I am so confused. The major thing is what I do different than my wife, who does the same "prepaid" plan is using WhatsApp. I do chat international with family.

"Airplane mode turns off the WiFi, so that does not work at all." You can turn on the WiFi again after enabling the Airplane mode, but Airplane mode will disable the telephony functionality (phone call & SMS). That said, if you want to be sure, you might want to turn off the Mobile Data setting so that you won't accidentally use it if you get disconnected from the WiFi.

As above. Not having a "data plan" doesn't mean you don't have mobile data, it means you pay for any mobile data usage according to the specific rates for your phone service as defined by T-Mobile (you may want to check online or customer service for the exact prices). When outside WiFi's range you'll be using mobile data unless you disable it as commented before AND informed by your own customer service. It goes without saying that, when you have no internet access (i.e. both WiFi disabled or inaccessible and mobile data disabled), NO internet service will work and that include Whatsapp.

As mentioned in comments, Whatsapp does not use mobile network directly.  It just uses data from the phone.
If the Wifi signal is weak, or if Wifi is not connected and your mobile data is on, then the Phone will use the mobile network for data.  This applies to,  many other apps that need data.
When you are home, turn off mobile data.  This can be automated by a number of apps for Profile management.  This way, you can still receive phone calls.

Thanks. It is important to be able to receive phone calls for medical purposes. I will try some things. Time will tell.
